# Cypress - New test file not showing in cypress UI

Tags: cypress

Creating a new test file in Cypress folder `integration` is not showing in the Cypress UI.
In this print-screen I have created a new file called: `NewTest.spec.js` (in green). It is not showing in Cypress.
[image]
It used to work

Comment: Does your `cypress.json` file contain `testFiles[]` ?

Answer (score 7):

In case you have a testFiles list defined inside the cypress.json file, Cypress will not include all of spec files found within the integration folder and will instead use that list to populate the suite.

So, check cypress.json and add the new spec file to the appropriate place in the order.

```
"testFiles": [
     "FirstTest.spec.js",
     "NewTest.spec.js",
     "ThirdTest.spec.js"
]
```

Answer (score 6):

In the latest version of Cypress, make sure your file is named [filename]**.cy**.js

Answer (score 2):

This is for cypress 10 and above - You can also specify the spec pattern in cypress.config.js as below, for all of the files to show up.
No need to name the files as [filename].cy.js for these to show up.

```
 const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "cypress/e2e/**/*.*",
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In `cypress.config.ts` you need to define your pattern with **specPattern**:

Like this:

```
import { defineConfig } from "cypress";

export default defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: 'cypress/integration/*.cy.ts', // write your pattern here
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      // implement node event listeners here
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was missing the .cy on the name of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Check that you are not missing .cy in the name of the file. filename.cy.js

Comment: There are 2 answers pointing that out already.